# Undetermined Coefficients problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Ok so I have this problem that I've been stuck on now for over an hour. I'm hoping someone can point out if I'm doing something wrong or what I am supposed to do next. It is an initial value problem in the undetermined coefficients section.

The problem says

$y'-y=1$, $y(0)=0$

I've tried solving for the first part, the general solution, Where I got $r=2$. I thought it was fairly simple, but according to the answer its not even in there.

I also tried setting $y_p=At$ and setting it equal to $At + b$. Nothing seems to be working.

The correct answer is $y=e^t-1$

Can anyone see what we are supposed to do in this problem? Thank you soo much in advance!

Comment: For particular solution, you should set $y_p=A$

Comment: Actually that does make sense... Because then I will get A=-1

Comment: It make sense, your solution will be $y=y_h+y_p \Rightarrow y=y_h+A \Rightarrow y=y_h-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look for the homogeneous solution (right hand side = 0). Generally, the solution to $y' - ay = 0$ is $e^{at}$. In your case $a=1$, so we have the homogeneous solution $y_h = e^t$.

Next, we find the particular solution to account for the fact that the right hand side is not zero. This is easy since the right hand side is constant $1$ - we have a particular solution $y_p = -1$.

The sum of these is the solution to your differential equation:

$$y = y_h + y_p = e^{t} - 1$$

We can also verify that $$y(0) = e^0 - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0$$ which was the initial condition.

Comment: Thank you! I will accept answer when it lets me. I kept looking in the book and couldn't see anywhere about the general solution any equation of this form.

Comment: @JeremyRowler The equation $y' - y = 0$ is separable. You can rewrite it as $\frac{dy}{y} = dx$ and solve by integration.

Answer (score 1):

In such a case the particular solution you are looking for is a constant one and not a linear one, since the inhomogeneous term is constant and the constant function does not satisfy the equation.

Hence you find as a particular solution the function $y_p=-1$, and as the general solution  of the homogeneous equation is $c\mathrm{e}^t$, then the general solution of the corresponding inhomogeneous is $-1+c\mathrm{e}^t$ - The constant $c4 is determined from the initial data, and it is equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Another nice approach that works for problems like this is to use an *integrating factor*.

In your particular situation, note that $-t$ is an antiderivative of $-1$ with respect to $t,$ and so $$\left(e^{-t}\right)'=-e^{-t}$$ by Chain Rule. Now, since $e^{-t}$ is never $0,$ then the following two equations are equivalent:

$$y'-y=1\\e^{-t}y'-e^{-t}y=e^{-t}.$$ by the work above, we can rewrite the latter equation as $$e^{-t}y'+\left(e^{-t}\right)'y=e^{-t},$$ which we can rewrite by Product Rule as $$\left(e^{-t}y\right)'=e^{-t}.$$ Integrating both sides with respect to $t$ gives us $$e^{-t}y=-e^{-t}+C\\y=-1+Ce^t$$ for some constant $C$. Using the initial value given, we have $$0=y(0)=-1+Ce^0=-1+C,$$ so $C=1,$ and so $$y=-1+e^t,$$ as desired.

More generally, if you have a differential equation that can be written as $$y'+f(t)y=g(t)$$ for some integrable functions $f(t)$ and $g(t),$ then letting $u(t)$ be any antiderivative of $f(t),$ we can multiply both sides by $e^{u(t)}$ to get the equivalent equation $$\left(e^{u(t)}y\right)'=g(t)e^{u(t)},$$ so that $$e^{u(t)}y=\int g(t)e^{u(t)}\,dt\\y=e^{-u(t)}\int g(t)e^{u(t)}\,dt.$$