# How do I solve this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ty' +y= 2t$$ 
I just don't get how to solve it.
I tried dividing the equation by $t$ but that didn't lead me anywhere
someone please help me with this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:
\begin{align}
t \frac{dy}{dt} + y &= 2t \\
\frac{d}{dt}(ty)&=2t \\
d(ty) &= 2t \, dt \\
\int d(ty) &= \int 2t \, dt
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: What is the derivative of $t\cdot y$ with respect to $t$? Use this to rewrite the left-hand side, which will make it easier to solve the equation.

**Note**: This is a particularly nice linear first-order ODE. Some will be less "obvious," and in such cases, you may want to use an *integrating factor*. I describe this method in more detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/715616/28900), if you're curious.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that i was over thinking. I thought that the function had to be something more complicated the this

Comment: Well, you should get a general solution of $y=t+\frac Ct$ for some constant $C.$ This can be readily verified by substitution into the ODE. Don't worry about it, though. I'm a chronic overthinker, myself.

Answer (score 4):

$y'+\frac{1}{t}y=2$ is a linear first order differetial equation. There is a formula:

$y=e^{-\int (1/t)dt}\left(\int 2 e^{\int (1/t)dt}dt+C\right)=\frac{1}{t}(t^2+C).$

Comment: Isn't using an integrating factor better?

Comment: May be. I do not know.

Comment: @BCLC: That formula comes about from the use of an integrating factor. Basically, an integrating factor is to that formula as completing the square is to the quadratic formula.

Comment: Yesm That is true. But formula is formula. It works well.

Comment: Oh right it does. But memorization is just so... http://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/09/10/is-memorization-necessary-evil-or-both/